# IIS takes long time to respond with MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

IIS 7.0 is taking long time to start sending the response to the browser.

The application Log files show that the action inside the controller is returning the data in milli seconds (I put the stopwatch.stop just before the return statement and wrote it to the log file), but IIS starts sending after some time(1 sec).

In the browser, developer tools shows the waiting time as 1 Sec + Controller's Milli seconds, fiddler also shows the same.

This is not an app pool issue as I am not getting the issue in the first run, I'm facing the issue almost in every run.